# Rails: Customize Validation Error Messages on Nested Form Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have a nested form object "Owner" that is creating a User along with an Account. In account.rb:

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
has_many :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
```

Then in my form for creating an account, I have my account fields, then fields_for Owner. That works all fine and dandy and creates an account along with an owner, but I'd like to enhance the user experience a bit with the validation error messages. Right now, the will come back as:

- (account attribute) can't be blank
- (other account attribute) can't be blank

Which are fine and normal, but then these are what conern me:

- Users is invalid
- Owner password can't be blank
- Owner password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
- Owner first name can't be blank

And so on and so forth for all of my validations.

First of all, I just want it to say "Password can't be blank", "First name can't be blank." Basically I don't want the user to see anything having to do with "Owner". They don't see it on the form...nothing says owner on the front end, so the user experience is less than ideal for it to say Owner. Its really just a naming convention on the back end that I don't want my users to think about at all. Call me a perfectionist, but is it possible to remove the nested object from the message and make it behave as if they were all part of the same model?

Also, what gives with the "Users is invalid"?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is very old, but I landed here and wanted to share what worked for me with a newer version of Rails.

You can customize the way attributes for `account/owner` are rendered in your `config/locales/en.yml` to remove the 'Owner' prefix:

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        account/owner:
          # optional, Rails 6+, further customize error messages. This is the default
          format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    attributes:
      account/owner:
        password: "Password" # defaults to 'Owner password' since nested
        first_name: "First name" # have to do this for each attribute
```

I know the `%{attribute} %{message}` bit is Rails 6+, not sure about the attribute customization.

Answer (score 0):

My validation errors consisted of this code, which I rendered as a partial throughout my app:

```
<% if validation_errors.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <i class="icon-notice"></i>
    <b>Please correct the following errors:</b>
    <ul>
      <% validation_errors.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I had to modify this as follows for this special case:

```
<% if @account.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <i class="icon-notice"></i>
    <b>Please correct the following errors:</b>
    <ul>
      <% @account.errors.delete(:users) %>
      <% @account.errors.each do |field, msg| %>
        <li><%= field.to_s.sub('owner.', '').humanize.capitalize %> <%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So you can see the different here: Instead of errors.full_messages, I used errors.field followed by errors.msg separately so that I could manipulate the field. I removed owner from the string and made it humanized and capitalized, and just removed the case of the users is invalid. This gave me a nicely formatted, better user experience that I wanted.

Hope this helps someone. Cheers.